# exception is: java.net.unknownhostexception: smtp.gmail.com

Tags: ubuntu, smtp, ktor

I'm encountering a "couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout" error when trying to send emails using Ktor on my Ubuntu server. The issue occurs when running the email sending process on the server, but I don't face this problem on my local machine. I'm using the Gmail SMTP server for email sending. Below is the code I'm using with Ktor:

```
object MailConstants {

val GOOGLE_SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"

const val emailUsername = ""
const val emailPassword = ""

val mailer: Mailer = MailerBuilder
    .withSMTPServer(GOOGLE_SMTP_HOST, 587, emailUsername, emailPassword)
    .withTransportStrategy(TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS)
    .withSessionTimeout(500 * 1000)
    .buildMailer()

}


class SendMail {
    suspend fun execute(model: SendMailModel): Boolean = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        return@withContext try {

            val email: Email = EmailBuilder.startingBlank()
                .from(Constants.APP_NAME, MailConstants.emailUsername)
                .to(Constants.APP_NAME, model.mailAddress)
                .withSubject(model.title)
                .withPlainText(model.message)
                .buildEmail()

            MailConstants.mailer.sendMail(email)
            true
        } catch (e: java.net.ConnectException) {
            println("ConnectException: " + e.message)
            false
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Unhandled exception while send email ${e.javaClass.name} from ${e.javaClass.packageName}")
            false
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone who has knowledge about resolving this issue or has encountered a similar problem provide assistance? Could the issue be related to my SSL certificate (I'm using Let's Encrypt)? I would greatly appreciate any hints or solution suggestions that would help me understand the exact cause of the problem and how to resolve it.

Email password = G-mail app password

Firewall;

[image: Firewall]

Error Message;

```
couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout 500000; nested exception is: java.net.unknownhostexception: smtp.gmail.com
```